# Human readable documentation current WebSphere configuration

Tags: java, documentation, websphere, application-server

Currently I'm working with a bunch of WebSphere Application Servers for some Java applications. Unfortunately there is poor documentation of the configuration of these servers. I know there a possibilities to generate scripts and configuration archives to migrate these settings. But I was wondering if there is a way to get the server configuration in a human readable format. Does any of you know if there are application servers (WebSphere in particular) that have such a function?

Edit:
Forgot to mention that I work with version 6.1 of WebSphere.

Comment: Hi, I'm not aware of anything official, however I have a set of Jython scripts exporting some parts of the configuration into XML. Some parts = configuration on node / server / cluster level, strictly cell level things like global security are not exported. What you get is web container settings, jvm, resources (JDBC, JMS, MQ queues), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know, if you will consider it 'human readable' but you can export the cell configuration in the property based format using following `wsadmin` task:

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName  ConfigProperties_cell.props]')
```

it will give you something like:

```
#
# SubSection 1.0 # JDBCProvider attributes
#
ResourceType=JDBCProvider
ImplementingResourceType=JDBCProvider
ResourceId=Cell=myCell:JDBCProvider=ID#builtin_jdbcprovider
#

#
#Properties
#
classpath={${DERBY_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/derby.jar,/my.jar}
implementationClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource
name=Derby JDBC Provider (XA)
nativepath={}
description=Built-in Derby JDBC Provider (XA)
providerType=Derby JDBC Provider (XA)
xa=true #boolean
```

For more details see:

- [Extracting properties files using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_7extractprops.html?lang=en)
- [Using properties files to manage system configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_property_configuration.html?lang=en)
- [PropertiesBasedConfiguration command group for the AdminTask](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_7propbasedconfig.html?lang=en)

Comment: Unfortunately extractConfigProperties is not available for WebSphere 6.1 (I should have mentioned that in the question).

Comment: @pjanssen WebSphere 6.1 is for long out of support now. You should move to the newer version as soon as possible. And yes, unfortunately property based configuration works from v7.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I would if I could.